# how to install zeromq for node.js

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I want to install zeromq for node.js in Windows 7 64-bit. I tried with

```
npm install zmq
```

It gave `phython.exe` is missing. After installing that `python (2.7.3)`.
Again it gave some build error, which is as follows:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe  failed with exit code: 1`

Comment: do you want to install on a 32bit or 64bit windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 1**

Improvements were made, now `npm install zmq` works, but you still need Win SDK 7 and VS C++ 2010, I think.

**Original Answer**

Unfortunately `npm install zmq` still don't work, but you can install it from local repo.

[mscdex](https://github.com/mscdex) forked the zeromq.node repo, and added windows support, so just clone his [zeromq.node](https://github.com/mscdex/zeromq.node)

But before build you need some prerequisites:

- Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 ([Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express) is fine)
- [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Run the Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt from Start menu / Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1

go to the cloned directory, and type

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```

this should work on windows 7 64bit. I cloned zeromq.node into my node project dir, so in my `app.js` i could `require('./zeromq.node')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Wow that was a lot of work! Getting the Windows 7 SDK installed involved uninstalling the newest C++ compiler (I think 10.4.xxx is incompatible). Source: "Had a similar problem which turned out to be that the SDK 7.1 does NOT install if you have a newer vcredist_x86.exe than version 10.0.30319 of Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable... I had 10.0.30419 installed... removed it through control panel "remove programs" and then the SDK 7.1 installed."

Comment: @jcollum My answer is mainly for win7 64bit, so I installed vcredist_x64.exe not vcredist_x86.exe. For installing it on a 32bit windows I used the work of [Matthiasg](https://github.com/matthiasg/zeromq-node-windows)

Comment: No longer work with newer nodejs and vs2012 but vs2015 also have yet another error `pfnDliNotifyHook2`. **Fixed** this with `npm -g install npm@next` with vs2015. Refer to [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/972) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38647149/186334)

Answer (score 4):

I had alot of trouble myself and eventually got it installed after hours of reading and trying diff things out:

1. Install python. Make sure Python 2.7.x installed and not 3.x (i used https://www.python.org but cygwin's python might work too)
    Confirm by running below:

   `$ python -V
   Python 2.7.9`
2. set PYTHON env variable, whereever you installed it (or cygwin's bin directory if installing python that way):

   PYTHON=C:\dev\python\python.exe
3. Set what folder python.exe added onto your PATH variable:

   PATH=C:\dev\python\;
4. needed this node-gyp installed manually:

   `$ npm install -g node-gyp
   ... Got slightly further...`
5. So I quit with trying to get it to install with my current Visual C++ 2010 and got Visual C++ 2012 to work (think 2013 may work too):
   so installed '[Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673)'
   Should install the '[2012 Visual C++ Redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)' (if not, install separately).

   Also had '[Windows7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)' already installed per balazs instructions so probably need that too.

   Now try on Windows command line and specify the version to use:

   `$ npm install --msvs_version=2012 zmq
   and it worked!`

   Note: wanted to mention what I already had installed. Already had 'Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express' installed (which installed Visual C++ 2010 Redistributables) 
     and Windows7 SDK since I was kinda following balazs instructions above.

   Then I tried installing: 
   'Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1'
   'Visual C++ SP1 Compiler Update for Windows SDK 7.1'

   Since none of that 2010 worked, I went with 2012. 
   Maybe someone can figure out if possible to make it work with C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I did not look into recent changes in that package but I wrote https://github.com/matthiasg/zeromq-node-windows for our own projects which added minor changes to the zeromq-node project to make it work in Windows... as it says in the readme I don't offer support , but maybe that will get you started ?

Answer (score 1):

This thread was very useful, here's what worked for me today on Win10:

1. Download / install zmq binaries for windows
2. Download / install node.js for windows
3. Get miniconda2 or similar in case you have python3 (python 2 required for the steps below build)
4. Get VS 2013 (any version should do) VS '15 doesn't work at this time
5. From a python2 prompt: `npm install --msvs_version=2013 zmq`

Comment: I can't compile with vs2012 but managed to fix with vs2015. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**The latest update:**

Windows 8.1, node v4.4.5, npm v3.10.5

1. Ensure python2 environment as usual
2. Install Windows SDK (mine 8.1)
3. Install VS2015 Community and select Common Tools for Visual C++
4. ===> `npm -g install npm@next` see [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/972)
5. `npm install --msvs_version=2015 zmq`

Note: I can't build with vs2012 anymore and all the suggested above not working with build error `error c2240 cannot convert from 'v8::Value *' to 'v8:object *volatile'`. Maybe because of the newer nodejs v4.4.5 (someone can clarify this?).

However using vs2015 produce build error `win_delay_load_hook.c(34): error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2'`. I fix this using `npm@next` as mentioned above.